# sum column's amount.i want calculate 1000+2000+3000+4000

Tags: jtable

how i can calculate JTable column .i want calculate 1000+2000+3000+4000 and put it end of column amount

amount|name|id

1000|x|1
 2000|y|2
 3000|w|3
 4000|z|4

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
//Global declaration
int a=0,b=0;

DefaultTbleModel model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
JTable table=new JTable(model);

for(int i=0;i<table.getRowCount();i++){
            a=a+Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).get(column));

            b=b+Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).get(column));
        }
        tj=Integer.toString(a);
        tb=Integer.toString(b);
        Object[] d1={"Total",tj,tb};
        model.addRow(d1);
```